# CocoaPods does install ios.vendored_frameworks, but NOT ios.frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

i've created a pod to include a vendored framework to a new project. this works fine. but for my project i need some other standard iOS frameworks. i do not want to add them manually, but i want my pod to do this automatically, by giving:

```
   s.ios.frameworks = 'QuartzCore', 'SystemConfiguration', 'CoreMotion', 'CFNetwork', 'UIKit', 'Foundation', 'CoreBluetooth', 'CoreGraphics', 'CoreLocation'
```

in my podspec file. if i run

```
pod install
```

the integration of the vendored frameworks just works fine. i get no warnings or errors. but the iOS frameworks don't get included to my project.

Comment: Does your project build though?

Comment: yes it does. i also checked the validation of my podspec file with `pod spec lint`. everything seems good. it just doesn't install the standard frameworks.

Comment: Then this is probably because CocoaPods doesn't actually alter your `.xcodeproj`, it creates its own. If you poke through the `.xcconfig` files and `Pods.xcodeproj` you'll find the frameworks.

Comment: i did this a few times, there are no frameworks. if i run `pod install` i only get `Installed Frameworks:` for the vendored ones. it seems like it just doesn't recognise the standard frameworks..?

Comment: just to be sure, i do not have to give a separate source for the standard frameworks in my pod spec file!?